# Git for Windows pastes clipboard on <enter>

Tags: windows, git, bash, mintty

Installed Git for Windows 2.14.1.  Pressing the 'Enter' button in the Git Bash terminal pastes the clipboard.  All options are default.  I've also tried options in many different configurations.  But I can't figure out how to stop the pasting on pressing 'Enter'.

Could it be a Windows setting (Windows 7)?

My Windows home directory is a shared drive.  Which has caused issues in the past, but this doesn't seem like it would be related.

Note, I tried on a different computer which did not display the same issue.  This would seem to point to configuration or Windows environment issues.  I've cleaned up all configuration I can find (.git*, .mintty*, old install location) and installed fresh, yet still run into the same issue.

Re-installing Git for Windows 2.10.1 (previous version used) is successful and does not have the pasting side effect.

Comment: As a data point, I've recently updated from 2.10.x to 2.14.x on a Windows 7 PC and did not have this effect. Do you have any keyboard macros or mouse macros setup?  Is your keyboard or mouse one that has a special config manager app installed to manage it?  Since right-clicking on a terminal or cmd windows is the default paste action, there may be an interaction...

Comment: Other things to consider - for Git-bash.exe, it should say "MINGW32": at the start of the window title; If so, can you try Git-cmd.exe (in your main Git directory); also can try the same in a normal windows command window instead (Git should be added to your PATH and run okay there).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that effect on recent Git.

COPY and PASTE are still linked to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>.

Check if the issue persists with the [latest release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) 2.14.2 ([`PortableGit-2.14.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.14.2-64-bit.7z.exe))